# Load Times for Ajax vary based on the calling script?

Tags: ajax, performance, load

I have a script that executes an Ajax call when a user clicks on a Yes No button in the main form.  When I look at the dev tools Network tab I see load times for this call of 2.5 to 3 seconds.
[image: Dev Tools screen shot]

I have tried both GET and POST.

So I start trying to debug this as it is causing some performance issues with my page.   My first idea is to take the same ajax routine and access it directly from the browser.
Doing this I see load times averaging about 400ms.

Next I try write a small script to do the actual ajax call 
[image]

Then I try writing a small script to call the ajax call the same way my big one does.    Load times very similar to the 400ms ones when the page directly called.

My main page is a pretty complex page.  But anyone have any idea why the ajax times are almost ten time longer???
Have tried this in both Chrome and Firefox.

Added code for ajax call.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../includes/ajax/_ver5/results_update.php",
        data: {yr: 2019, dsim: 'no', rid: 477, rnum: 1, line: 1, flt: 33, bid: 6533, chid: 4, uid: 2, type: "chkin", chkin: 'Y'},
        dataType: 'json', timeout: 3000,
        success: function (dataret) {
            // process_ajax(dataret, flt);
        }
    });
```

Thanks 
Dave

Comment: Can you show some code?. so that we see how you are making the ajax calls

Comment: add coded for Ajax call.